# How to know if your computer has a GD install

Tags: php

I am working on file upload and I am reading some notes on it. And it is talking about GD. Now I am running windows 7. Where do I go check to see if there is anything called GD so I can do my upload. I know i need to make sure it is activated in my php. I know when you use wamp server you can find it. Well this semster I am not using wampserver we are only using navicat and filezila. So I am very confused about it.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (extension_loaded('gd') && function_exists('gd_info')) {
    echo "It looks like GD is installed";
}
```

Take a look at this, if you dont now how to enable it :
http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?589486-How-to-check-if-GD-is-installed-and-if-so-enable-it

Comment: Isn't `extension_loaded('gd')` sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $gdInstalled = extension_loaded('gd');
```

Answer (score 0):

just go to terminal and type the below

```
php -r \phpinfo\(\)\; | grep 'GD'
```

it should return something like this

```
GD Support => enabled
GD Version => 2.1.1-dev
```